# How to convert date to hours

Tags: php, datetime

I am having :

```
hours1 : 403440
```

and `date2 as :`2016/01/10

I need to convert date2 in hours and find the difference between the two which should again be in hours.

Comment: Does this not answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1778907/1212968

Comment: Hi aidan, I had went through the above artical question, also tried the same, but the suggestions don't work for my question.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `date` is a unix timestamp which is in seconds so multiple your hours by 3600 (3600 seconds per hour).

```
$hours1 = 403440 * 3600;
$date1 = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $hours1);
echo $date1;
```

Output:

```
09-01-2016 19:00:00
```

Per your update your code should be:

```
$date2 = strtotime('2016/01/10');//get date to seconds from 1970
$hours1 = 403440 * 3600; // convert from hours to seconds
echo ($date2 - $hours1)/3600;//subtract seconds then divide by 3600 to get how many hours difference is
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of date() is unix timestamp which is the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
So, if $hours1 is number of hours since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC, it should be 
    `date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$hours1*3600);`
to yield the correct date string.

On the other hand, `$hours2=(strtotime($date2)/3600);` is giving you the correct number of hours since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: But initial date2 have the value : date2=2016/01/10   . When i use $hours2=(strtotime($date2)/3600); why does it give January 1 1970 00:00:00 ?

Comment: strtotime() should return an integer of unix timestamp. I don't understand why you get a string of ' January 1 1970 00:00:00 '.

Comment: strtotime() give the number of second since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. $hours2 is the number of hours since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC, because you divide it by 3600.

Comment: Basically I want to find the difference between hours1 : 403440 and date2 as : 2016/01/10  for which i need to do proper conversion and find the difference.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and get back @quickpick

Comment: The point is make sure you  convert to the same time unit when doing comparison and calcuation.

Comment: Say... $time1 = 403440 * 3600; $time2 = strtotime($date2); Then these both are in number of seconds which you can compare and calculate.

Comment: what if i want both is hours.

Comment: @pihu why dont you update your question to state **exactly** what you want.

Comment: Hi @chris85 I have update the question, Kindly suggest.

Comment: Thanks @chris84 and quickpick, I am making changes as per your suggestion and update you once done.

Comment: Thanks @quickpick yours suggestion worked and were helpful.